# Extracting a substring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I have a string like this: "/Myapp/auth/hrHeadcount+ME+All IOU+Headcount+Grade" and I want to save only the "**HeadCount**" in another string. How can I do that?

Comment: nnstring format is fix or it will change dynamically ?

Comment: what do you mean? is HeadCount a variable or something?

Comment: Is there any rule on how your input is formatted? Else, `NSString* headCount = @"HeadCount";` would be working...

Comment: Actually the above string is apart of my url,And this format will be same,but the string that comes after "/" and "+" may change.And need to fetch the value whiche comes in the place of "Headcount"(/../.../..+....+....+Headcount+....")

Comment: But how are you supposed to recognize this one word amongst the other words?  If it's a parameter (which has a name you can recognise) then why isn't it being passed as a URL parameter?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *srcStr = @"/Myapp/auth/hrHeadcount+ME+All IOU+Headcount+Grade";
NSString *dstStr = [[srcStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"] objectAtIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it will have same format then u can do the following

```
NSString *string1 = @"/Myapp/auth/hrHeadcount+ME+All IOU+Headcount+Grade";
NSArray *stringArray = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *string2 = stringArray[3];
NSArray *finalArray = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSString *finalString = finalArray[0];
```

final String will have the headCount u require

Comment: Quicker is: `NSString *finalString = @"Headcount";`.

Comment: nope... head count is a variable which she is referring to its a url so it will change

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Although I'm not sure the word is always in the same place in the URL.

Comment: I've editted my comment.  Can't you see the editted version?

Comment: Yes.  There is no clue as to which of those words is the one you want.  URLs can have parameters which are used to pass this kind of information between the client and the server.

Comment: i dint see that comment... i thought she required the first head count...the comments change everything hmmm...